# Running mySQL queries from a script

Tags: mysql

For my database class the teacher assigned us to use Oracle SQL to design an application. Because I have more experience with mySQL he said I could use it instead.

I want to make my assignment look as simliar to his example as possible. What his example consists of of is one file run.sql that looks like this:

```
@start //this runs start.sql which creates the tables

DESC table_name; //do this for all tables

@insert //this runs insert.sql that creates dummy data

SELECT * FROM table_name; //do this for all tables

@query //this runs query.sql that runs our sample queries

@drop //this kills all the data
```

Is there a way to do something simliar?

Namely a way to write a query that calls external queries and outputs all data to an output.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'source' to input the *.sql files

use 'create procedure' to generate the 'drop' function

use "into outfile '/file/path';"  on your select to write out.

double redirect to append:  "into outfile '>>/file/path';"

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this? SOURCE run.sql INTO OUTFILE 'output.txt';

Comment: I found this works: mysql -p dbname < foo.sql > foo.txt but doesn't contain all output or pretty print.

Answer (score 0):

The `source` command for the `mysql` command-line client could do the job here:

```
source start.sql;

DESC table_name;
```

You can get more commands with `help`.

Comment: that worked! now just to figure out how to get it to print output

Comment: It should display the output of any queries it runs by default. If you need formatting, looks like @ChrisSM has you covered.